# Remove a substring from lines starting with a specific character

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, fasta

I am trying to change long names in rows starting with `>`, so that I only keep the part till `Stage_V_sporulation_protein...`:

```
>tr_A0A024P1W8_A0A024P1W8_9BACI_Stage_V_sporulation_protein_AE_OS=Halobacillus_karajensis_OX=195088_GN=BN983_00096_PE=4_SV=1
MTFLWAFLVGGGICVIGQILLDVFKLTPAHVMSSFVVAGAVLDAFDLYDNLIRFAGGGATVPITSFGHSLLHGAMEQADEHGVIGVAIGIFELTSAGIASAILFGFIVAVIFKPKG
>tr_A0A060LWV2_A0A060LWV2_9BACI_SpoIVAD_sporulation_protein_AEB_OS=Alkalihalobacillus_lehensis_G1_OX=1246626_GN=BleG1_2089_PE=4_SV=1
MIFLWAFLVGGVICVIGQLLMDVVKLTPAHTMSTLVVSGAVLAGFGLYEPLVDFAGAGATVPITSFGNSLVQGAMEEANQVGLIGIITGIFEITSAGISAAIIFGFIAALIFKPKG
```

I am doing a loop:

```
cat file.txt | while read line; do 
  if [[ $line = \>* ]] ; then
    cut -d_ -f1-4 $line; 
  fi; 
done
```

but in addresses files but not rows in the file (I get `cut: >>tr_A0A024P1W8_A0A024P1W8_9BACI_Stage_V_sporulation_protein_AE_OS=Halobacillus_karajensis_OX=195088_GN=BN983_00096_PE=4_SV=1: No such file or directory`).

My desired output is:

```
>tr_A0A024P1W8_A0A024P1W8_9BACI        
MTFLWAFLVGGGICVIGQILLDVFKLTPAHVMSSFVVAGAVLDAFDLYDNLIRFAGGGATVPITSFGHSLLHGAMEQADEHGVIGVAIGIFELTSAGIASAILFGFIVAVIFKPKG
>tr_A0A060LWV2_A0A060LWV2_9BACI        
MIFLWAFLVGGVICVIGQLLMDVVKLTPAHTMSTLVVSGAVLAGFGLYEPLVDFAGAGATVPITSFGNSLVQGAMEEANQVGLIGIITGIFEITSAGISAAIIFGFIAALIFKPKG
```

How do I change actual rows?

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: Instead of `cat file.txt | while ...`, do `while read line; do ...  done < file.txt`. But instead of that, do `awk '...' file.txt`.  This is trivial with `awk`, and `awk` is a tool you should be familiar with. (Everyone should know `awk`!)

Comment: This seems trivial enough that you could use `sed`: `sed -e '/^>/s/_Stage_V.*//'`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell if I were familiar with `awk` I would probably not raise a question here. Some tolerance to beginners would be appreciated.

Comment: But it's not at all clear what you mean by "but in addresses files but not rows in the file."

Comment: @plnnvkv Sorry, I didn't intend to demonstrate any intolerance.  I assume you are not familiar with `awk` and am merely trying to bring it to your attention.  But `sed` is probably sufficient for your use case.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks for the `sed` option! It would work if all the lines would contain `Stage_V` but it's not the case. I changed the input accordingly, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current state of the question, it seems easiest to do:

```
awk '/^>/ {print $1,$2,$3,$4; next}1' FS=_ OFS=_ file.txt
```

Lines that match the `>` at the beginning of the line get only the first four fields printed, separated by `_` (the value of `OFS`).  Lines that do not match are printing unchanged.

Comment: NIce. Can also use `/^>/ {NF=4}1` (GNU awk, not sure about other implementations).

Comment: @Sundeep The `NF=4` technique is nice, but it is indeed a gnu-ism.

Answer (score 1):

One way using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -E '/^>/s/(.*)_Stage_V_sporulation_protein/\1/' file
```

Comment: Sorry I've already mentioned above, not all lines contain `Stage_V_sporulation_protein`, can be different in different lines

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` one-liner would be:

```
sed '/^>/s/^\(\([^_]*_\)\{3\}[^_]*\).*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner to process the headers in your FASTA file:

```
perl -lpe 'if ( m{^>} ) { @f = split m{_}, $_; splice @f, 4; $_ = join "_", @f; }' file.txt > out.txt
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

The one-liner uses [`split`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) to split the input string on underscore into the array `@f`.
Then [`splice`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice) is used to remove from the array all elements except for the first 4 elements.
Finally, [`join`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join) joins these elements on an underscore.
All of the above is wrapped inside `if ( m{^>} ) { ... }` in order to limit the costly string manipulations only to the FASTA headers (the lines that start with `>`).

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)